# ToolStripProgressBar RightToLeftLayout Set Property issue

Tags: winforms, propertyinfo

Here I'm trying to set the RIghtToLeftLayout property of ToolStripProgressBar, when i try to set the value either true or false, I'm getting this error.....

**at System.Windows.Forms.ToolStripProgressBar.set_RightToLeftLayout(Boolean value)
   Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

Here is the code:

```
PropertyInfo piRightToLeftLayout = ci.Type.GetProperty("RightToLeftLayout", typeof(bool));
if ((null != piRightToLeftLayout) && piRightToLeftLayout.CanWrite)
{
  piRightToLeftLayout.GetSetMethod().Invoke(ci.Value, new object[] { IsRightToLeft() });
}
```

IsRightToLeft() : returns either true or false.

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing it by reflection? `ToolStripProgressBar.RightToLeftLayout` is a public property.

In terms of your NullReferenceException, all the setter does is:

```
  set
  {
    this.ProgressBar.RightToLeftLayout = value;
  }
```

Which implies, the ProgressBar property is null, which seems odd. I'd like to know what you're doing prior to your call and how `ci` has been setup.